# PHP-5 mcrypt won't enable on nginx server ubuntu 14.04

Tags: php, ubuntu, nginx, mcrypt

I've been trying to install `mcrypt` extension for php5 on Ubuntu 14.04 ARM server running nginx.

**PROBLEM**

In `phpinfo()` I can only see the authors of `mcrypt` but the module itself is missing. I can't use mcrypt functionalities anywhere on that server.

**WHAT I TRIED**

Running `php5 -m` shows that `mcrypt` is installed.

In /etc/php5/fpm/php.ini I have the following `extension = /usr/lib/php5/20121212+lfs/mcrypt.so`. This I read in google after I tried only with `extension = mcrypt.so`. Neither gave result.

In /etc/php5/fpm/conf.d/20-mcrypt.ini I have this `extension=/usr/lib/php5/20121212+lfs/mcrypt.so` as well.

I restarted `php5-fpm` and `nginx` multiple times, I also tried `php5enmod mcrypt` which doesn't show any warnings or errors.

I created symlink between the .so and .ini file.

Any ideas?

Comment: It is best not to use mcrypt, it is abandonware, has not been updated in years and does not support standard PKCS#7 (née PKCS#5) padding, only non-standard null padding that can't even be used with binary data. mcrypt had many outstanding [bugs](https://sourceforge.net/p/mcrypt/bugs/) dating back to 2003. Instead consider using [defuse](https://github.com/defuse/php-encryption), it is being maintained and is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so it turns out that my only escape was to `purge php5-fpm`, reboot the server, then `apt-get install php5-fpm`, now everything is loaded correctly. I have no idea why this happens. If anyone has explaination I'll be happy to update my answer with it.